# モバイル版で、自己紹介が空の時のメッセージが英語のまま / about_me(nil).eigo? # => true

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 英語

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/9178/fsh

> This user has not filled their about me section yet.

On my iPhone 5, which is mainly configured to use English, using the website (not an app), I'm capable of reading the message saying the "about me" hasn't been filled out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PC版とモバイル版で違う文章なのですね・・・。

> このユーザーはまだ_自己紹介_を書いていません。

[Transifexで](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/english/41530075)上記のように訳したので、近日中にサイトに反映されると思います。